# How to return multiple selects as dataTable when using linq

Tags: c#

I'm very new to using linq and struggling with what it can and can't do compared to normal sql stuff.

I have a function that returns a dataTable and I would want it to return what slots gives. By only doing one select I can achieve this by using copyToDataTable as seen below.

```
        var slots = from parts1 in DT1.AsEnumerable()
                    join parts2 in DT2.AsEnumerable() on
                    parts1.Field<string>("Part_name") equals
                    parts2.Field<string>("Part_name")
                    where parts1.Field<string>("M0") != parts2.Field<string> 
                    ("M1")
                    select parts1;

        return slots.CopyToDataTable();
```

But when I try using multiple selects it doesn't work. Is there another way to do this that's similar to using copy? Or how else could I achieve this?

```
           var slots = from parts1 in DT1.AsEnumerable()
                    join parts2 in DT2.AsEnumerable() on
                    parts1.Field<string>("Part_name") equals
                    parts2.Field<string>("Part_name")
                    where parts1.Field<string>("M0") != parts2.Field<string> 
                    ("M1")
                    select new
                    { 
                        partName = parts1.Field<string>("Part_name"),
                        M0 = parts1.Field<string>("M0"),
                        M1 = parts2.Field<string>("M1")
                    };

           return slots;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/implement-copytodatatable-where-type-not-a-datarow

Comment: Add ToList() : (from ......).ToList();  So you can see all the values being returned.